# Inserting at head for a recursively defined linked list

Tags: recursion, linked-list

This [article](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/lazy-cons-lists.html) states

> However, this design does run into problems with some of the methods of the MutableSequence ABC. Most notably, insert and
>   __ delitem __ can't operate on position 0, because you can't change the head of the list when the only reference you have is to the head of
>   the list.

If we have a reference to the `head` node, why can't we just create a new `head` node that contains the old `head` node as its `tail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` and `__delitem__` methods of `MutableSequence` ABC are expected to do an in-place modification of the sequence you call them on.

This means that code like this should work

```
len(sequence) == 1
sequence.insert(0, <a value>)
sequence.insert(0, <a value>)
len(sequence) == 3
```

This code does not change the object that `sequence` refers to. This also means that if `sequence` actually refers to the head node of a linked list, you can't magically insert a new head node before it and have `sequence` refer to that.

This is the problem that the article refers to.

Comment: Thanks that's very insightful. However could you not implement by adding a new Slist at the end of the sequence, moving all of the self.head members down the chain to the next Slist, and replacing the self.head member at the head node with <a value>? –